# Edit core custom template (page.tpl / template.php / theme-settings.php)

Tags: 7, theming

How we add more fields in the **appearance -> settings -> "my template"**

So that the background image shows several titles and other information.

[image]

I added the fields in **theme-settings.php**, but when i am added new they cannot display at frontend. I changed the print code as well in **template.php**(code below).

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($banners); $i++) {
        $output .= '{ 
            "image" : "' . file_create_url($banners[$i]['image_path']) . '",
            "title" : "' . "<h2>" . fancy_title(t('@image_title', array('@image_title' => t($banners[$i]['image_title'])))) . "</h2>" . '",
            "subtitle" : "' . "<h3>" . fancy_title(t('@image_subtitle', array('@image_subtitle' => t($banners[$i]['image_subtitle'])))) . "</h3>" . '",
        },';
    }
```

I tested and if i change 'subtitle' to 'title' i can print that, but not both.

If anyone can give me a hint i would appreciate.
Cheers

**EDIT**

The fields that i need to print, are created in theme-settings.php with this code,

```
 // Image title
$img_form['image_title']       = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Title'),
    '#default_value' => $image_data['image_title']
);
// Image SUB title
$img_form['image_subtitle']       = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#subtitle' => t('subTitle'),
    '#default_value' => $image_data['image_subtitle']
);
```

printed in template.php with this code,

```
 for ($i = 0; $i < count($banners); $i++) {
        $output .= '{ 
            "image" : "' . file_create_url($banners[$i]['image_path']) . '",
            "title" : "' . "<h2>" . fancy_title(t('@image_title', array('@image_title' => t($banners[$i]['image_title'])))) . "</h2>" . '",
            "subtitle" : "' . "<h3>" . fancy_title(t('@image_subtitle', array('@image_subtitle' => t($banners[$i]['image_subtitle'])))) . "</h3>" . '",
        },';
    }
```

and called in page.tpl.php with this code,

```
 <?php if (theme_get_setting("slideshowType")=="image") : ?>
```

So, the second field created shows in drupal- settings - template, stores the info in the database, but isn't printed correctly in page.tpl

If any more info is needed i will provide it.

Ps. I'm new to drupal and PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading the answer given, i searched in the code to find how to pass the 2 fields, and after sometime i realized that was the **Javascript** that was in charge to print the variables in the target ID, and not the **PHP**

The original that printed the field:

```
 if (a(vars.slide_caption).length) {
            (api.getField("**title**")) ? a(vars.slide_caption).html(api.getField("**title**")) : a(vars.slide_caption).html("");
        }
```

To print 2 fields:

```
 if (a(vars.slide_caption).length) {
            (api.getField("**title**") && api.getField("**subtitle**")) ? a(vars.slide_caption).html(api.getField("**title**") + api.getField("**subtitle**")) : a(vars.slide_caption).html("");
        }
```

Thank you for your time. Would give +vote, but i don't have permissions.
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add more items/theme in your home page template, do the  following the steps..

1. Create a new **tpl** by editing existing **page.tpl.php**.
2. Add your fields into new **tpl**.
3. Name your new **tpl** as page--front.tpl.php.
4. Put your new template in `current-theme/templates`.

If you want to add more items in your theme options page do it in

**[hook_form_system_theme_settings_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!theme.api.php/function/hook_form_system_theme_settings_alter/7)**

Comment: I realized that i explained  the problem poorly, i added more info. Thanks for your time!

Comment: in **page.tpl**  you can access **image_title** value by calling **theme_get_setting("image_title");** and **theme_get_setting("image_subtitle");** for **image_subtitle** value

Comment: I try'd to use your solution, but with no success, but it gave-me some ideas to try.